# How to make glass shader?

Tags: glass, windows

New user. I'm trying to create a bedroom scene and can't get the window to be a glass shader.

See the image of from the Bender page on how to make glass. I think it is Cycles but I would like to also do it in EEVEE.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just want to ask a potentially stupid question JUST IN CASE. Have you made sure that your material is actually plugged into the Material Output node to the right of your screenshot? The Group Output node won't do anything, and that's what's going on in your screenshot. Sorry to ask a silly question, but I only have your screenshot to go on and that's the glaring issue I can see.

Comment: Microsoft has reared its… oh, never mind.

Comment: shader should link to surface,not group output.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 3):

What you did with the shader nodes should work in cycles. To make glass material for eevee, Create a new material, The material must be a principled BSDF node connecting to the material output node.[image] Set the transmission in the principled BSDF to 1.[image] Then enable screen space refraction in the settings of the material properties.[image] Then go to render properties and enable screen space reflection and also enable refraction in screen space reflection.[image] You can also lower the roughness to see more clear through your glass, it is your choice how clear you want your glass to be.[image]To change the color of your glass just set your color in the base color of the principled BSDF. You also can change the specular to 1 and IOR to 1.45 . And play with the refraction depth in the settings of the material properties to come up with the results you want.